# Use htaccess to redirect URL to app-specific deep-link

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do the following:

User visits URL with query parameter: `http://www.example.com/?invite=1234`

I then want them to be deep linked into the app on their iOS device, so they go to: `app_name://1234`

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in my `.htaccess` file?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule ^invite/(.*)/$ app_name://$1 [NC,L]
```

If `RewriteRule` won't work, can anyone send me an example code for `RewriteCond` or JavaScript to achieve what I need?

Comment: Use [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) instead

Comment: @ChrisG Why `Redirect`?!

Comment: @MrWhite Because we need the browser to run a request for `app_name://...` I guess, so the OS can send the user to the app, and that'll only happen if we redirect, afaik. Rewrite is about internal rewriting of the requested URL, isn't it? Unnoticed by the browser?

Comment: @ChrisG RewriteRule can do internal rewrites, or external redirects - it depends on the target URL (different origin than request URL -> automatic redirect), and flags used (`R` forces an external redirect.)

Comment: @CBroe I see, thanks for a non-arrogant clarification ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this will work with the iOS device, but anyway...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^invite/(.*)/$ app_name://$1 [NC,L]
> ```

This doesn't match the given URL. This would match a requested URL of the form `example.com/invite/1234/`. However, you are also matching *anything* - your example URL contains digits only.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, you need to use a `RewriteCond` directive in order to match the query string. So, to match `example.com/?invite=1234` (which has an empty URL-path), you would need to do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^invite=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ app_name://%1 [R,L]
```

The `%1` backreference refers back to the last matched *CondPattern*.

I've also restricted the `invite` parameter value to at least 1 character - or do you really want to allow empty parameter values through? If the value can be only digits then you should limit the pattern to only digits. eg. `^invite=(\d+)`.

I've include the `R` flag - since this would have to be an external redirect - if it's going to work at all.

However, this may not work at all unless Apache is aware of the `app_name` protocol. If its not then it will simply be seen as a *relative* URL and result in a malformed redirect.